# Setup version for module is not specified in magento2

Tags: magento2

I was trying to create a new module in magento2. I followed all the steps to create the module but I am still getting the below error :

"Setup version for module 'TW_Newmodule' is not specified. "

Please help me. What am I doing wrong in my module ?

Path of the code is app/code

You can download the code from here http://184.107.158.214/TW.zip .

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento 2.0.0 GA Launch.
    I am discussing about this post regarding to magento 2.0.0.

For Magento 2.0.0 general availability,
you must have to declared **registration.php and composer.json in your root**.
Also in your module attached above both of this file are not available.
For in magento2.0.0,

```
     In all .xml file xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation value are changed.so you have to update value for that.
```

Answer (score 1):

You module incomplete.  You need add composer.json and register.php files to root of module.

Also looks like you add module to list by self. Please use `bin/magento module:enable` for this.

For more details about module creation see in [Official Documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/create_module.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response . As you mentioned about register.php , what will it be code for that because wherever nowhere it was mentioned ...

Comment: see http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/component-registration.html

Comment: Hello Kandy , Thanks for your support , now the module has been successfully created . . but I am facing issue when I am trying to run the module it on the browser "http://127.0.0.1/magento2ce/newmodule/ ", I am getting 404 Error . Could you let me know if I need to add something in composer.json on the magento root  or any other setting ?